# What is the number of concurrent requests using SPDY in browser?

Tags: spdy, browser-support

As far as I have researched, I found out that each browser has a different number of maximum concurrent requests to the same domain ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768266/1299642 ). As i understood this applies to `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocols.

Does anyone know if the same is applied for the `SPDY` protocol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no limit](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft2#TOC-Overview) to the number of concurrent requests.

Whether this is a practical matter or not, I don't know, but I presume this is something realized in testing.

You should consider reviewing the HTTP2 spec to see if that has changed there since that is the standardized version of SPDY.

Comment: I understood that the SPDY is trying to remove the maximum concurrent request issue, but i do not know if this has been implemented in the ( few ) browsers that support SPDY. In other words if the browsers ( that support SPDY ) have removed the limit for the domains that serve SPDY.

Comment: @helly0d I wish I could provide more detail but work is keeping me occupied but I did want to comment that ALL browsers support SPDY except Opera-mini and, as expected, IE.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for your answer when you have some free time because today google is not my friend.

Comment: Found out this for anyone interested for resources : http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/09/05/domain-sharding-revisited/